# asp.net mvc unobtrusive validation evaluated eagerly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

In ASP.NET MVC Unobtrusive validation MaxLength , Range Data annotation attributes are evaluated eagerly. Is there a way to defer that during submit button and show validation error messages on Validation Summary ?

```
[MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "zip code length can not be greater than 5")]
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

This suppose is evaluated on tab index change.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#toptions) you can turn on/off.

Code below will not perform validation when focus leaves the control. I have added 2 other options just so you can see they are also avaialable but commented them out:

```
$('#your-control-id').validate({
       onfocusout: false//,
       //onkeyup: false,
       //onclick: false
});
```

Comment: Should be done using `$.validator.setDefaults({ onfocusout: false; });`